# Complex orientation of the Adams Summand

Tags: stable-homotopy, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

First lets fix a prime $p$ (I really care about $p=2$ but would be happy to know about other primes as well). When localized at a prime the spectrum $ku$ (Complex connective K-theory) splits as a wedge of suspensions of a spectrum $l$. In their paper on the Cooperation algebra of the Adams Summand, Baker-Richter state that the complex orientation $MU \to l$ factors through the complex orientation of $BP$ and that it can be arranged so that the image of $x_n \in \pi_{2n}MU$ and $v_i \in \pi_{2p^i-2}BP$ go to zero in $\pi_*l$. Let $BP(n)$ denote the "truncation" of $BP$ so that $\pi_*BP(n) \cong \pi_*BP/(v_{n+1},v_{n+2},...)$.
(This may not be the notation in the literature, but I am pretty sure I have seen people mention these objects).

My question is can we extend the complex orientation of $l$ over some of these other spectra?
Does the structure of $l$ and $l_*BP$ as a module over $BP(n)$ change a lot when going from $BP(n)$ to $BP(n+1)$?

Comment: ku splits as a wedge of (p-1) summands of l, so if you're mostly interested in p=2, well, ...

Comment: I understand that. My question is about whether or not we can factor the complex orientation through "truncations" of $BP$.

Comment: does it change the question if I ask about $ku$ instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the complex orientation can be factored through these truncations of BP.  Either classical methods (the Baas-Sullivan theory of manifolds with singularity - see Baas' "On bordism theory of manifolds with singularities") or more modern methods (see e.g. Strickland's "Products on MU-modules") produce truncated Brown-Peterson $BP\langle n\rangle$ as a tower of "quotients"
$$
MU \to \cdots \to BP \to \cdots \to BP\langle 2\rangle \to \ell \to H\mathbb{Z} \to H\mathbb{Z}/p
$$
and this produces a sequence of compatible complex orientations on these, provided of course that you've produced compatible multiplicative structures on all of the $BP\langle n\rangle$.

The problem doesn't really change if you use $ku$.  Also, note that $ku$ and $\ell$ have nicer and more natural multiplicative structures and orientations than any version of $BP\langle n\rangle$ is known to in general.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, what about the module structures? can I naively truncate the formulas in Ravenel or Wilson? Also, it occurred to me that it might just be easier to think about $l_*MU$ instead of $l_*BP$ for my particular issue. Can one get a similar result for truncations of $MU$? Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Sean: Yes, there is a similar result about truncations of MU.  So far as module structures, the left module structure of `$\ell_*, \ell_* BP$` are all restrictions to the module structures over `$BP_*, BP\langle n\rangle_*$`, or any other factorization obtained from the quotient map on homotopy groups.  I'm not sure which formulas you're after (the right unit, maybe?) but you can get it by modding out.

Comment: One small warning about ku that I didn't say is that the standard orientation of ku isn't the one that is compatible with $BP\langle 1\rangle$; it comes from a map `$MU_* \to ku_*$` that is a quotient by a different regular sequence.